# Testing tool for performance

Tags: testing, performance-testing, response-time, manual-testing

Which is the best Performance tool to measure the response time for a web application in IE10 and above.

I've used http watch and fiddler.

Kindly suggest any other tools, which are good and simple

Also kindly let me know what is memory leakage in mobiles.

I tried using the Developer tools it dint help.
The web pages which i need to test have a lot of dynamic fields, so if i click on any of the fields the debugger will close as the fields loads. Hence need an external tool to record the response time.

Comment: This is needed mainly to find the response times of the dynamic fields in one of the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using inbuilt "Developer Tools" in IE (Press F12 button on keyboard to open it)

Comment: In the developer tools I could not find where will it show the response time.  Also the problem in this is my webpage has many dynamic fields, if I open the debugger and click on any of these fields the debugger gets closed. Hence need an external tool.

Comment: Check out: http://www.httpwatch.com/

Comment: In Developer Tools, you can get response time from "Network" panel

Comment: Yes Jayapal found it, do you mean to tell that the Taken column is the response time ?

Comment: I've used http watch and fidller as well, wanted to find other tools which are simple n effective.

Comment: Yes, I would like you to take a look at time taken column to get response time.

Answer (score 0):

"Best" would depend on your criteria for what that means.  Best could mean one that is fast and easy to set up and use and can simulate traffic in a realistic scenario.  Or you might have a number of very technical requirements.  There are a number of "performance testing as a service" tools out there that meet the simplicity metric eg. you could try Nouvola DiveCloud http://www.nouvola.com/ who have a free plan with 600 user minutes per month.

Comment: I dint quite understand your point. but its mainly to find the response times of the dynamic fields in a page.